# How to extract substring between two characters/substrings

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string:

```
string1 = "my name is fname.lname and i live in xyz. my lname is not common"
```

I want to extract a substring from `string1` that is anything between the first empty space `" "` and `".lname"`. In the case above, the answer should be "fname.lname"`.

Comment: Your description contradicts with your expected output. You might need to add more details in your question, more specific rules about your extraction.

Comment: What is an "empty space"?

Comment: I gave my answer based on your original statement (sic), 'I want to get `string2` from `string1` which is anything between first space " " and ".lname"`. That seems clear enough, but now I notice that you say the desired result is "fname.lname". The first space follows the word "my" and since "between" is not inclusive, your statement can only mean that you want to return "name is fname". Please explain.

Comment: @ CarySwoveland .yeah it was confusing. I just want to return "fname.lname". forget about white/empty space.

Comment: The question is not confusing, it's contradictory. If you want to return `"fname.lname"` just return that literal string. If you want to return a string that satisfies a given rule, which in the example would return `"fname.lname"`, then what's the rule? For example, do you want the first substring containing no spaces that ends `.lname` (in which case `string1[/\S+\.lname\b/] #=> "fname.lname"`)? Isn't it obvious that a rule is needed?

Answer (score 2):

```
string1[/(?<= ).*?(?=\.lname\b)/]
  #=> "name is fname"
```

`(?<= )` is a *positive lookbehind* that requires the first character matched be immediately preceded by a space, but that space is not part of the match.

`(?=\.lname\b)` is a *positive lookahead* that requires the last character matched is immediately followed by the string `".lname"`<sup>1</sup>
, which is itself followed by a *word break* (`\b`), but that string is not part of the match. That ensures, for example, that `"\.lnamespace"` is not matched. If that should be matched, remove `\b`.

`.*?` matches zero more characters (`.*`), non-greedily (`?`). (Matches are by default *greedy*.) The non-greedy qualifier has the following effect:

```
"my name is fname.lname and fname.lname"[/(?<= ).*(?=\.lname\b)/]
  #=> "name is fname.lname and fname" 
"my name is fname.lname and fname.lname"[/(?<= ).*?(?=\.lname\b)/]
  #=> "name is fname"
```

In other words, the non-greedy (greedy) match matches the first (last) occurrence of `".lname"` in the string.

This could alternatively be written with a capture group and no lookarounds:

```
string1[/ (.*?)\.lname\b/, 1]
  #=> "name is fname"
```

This regular expression reads, "mactch a space followed by zero or more characters, saved in capture group 1, followed by the string `".name"` followed by a word break. This uses the form of [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) that has two arguments, a reference to a capture group.

Yet another way follows.

```
string1[(string1 =~ / /)+1..(string1 =~ /\.lname\b/)-1]
  #=> "name is fname"
```

<sup>1 The period in `".lname"` must be escaped because an unescaped period in a regular expression (except in a character class) matches *any* character.</sup>

Comment: sorry, i confused you guys. I just want to return "fname.lname". forget about white/empty space.